# create cypher file from pdf file using python(i would like to use blowfish algorithm)

Tags: python, encryption, file-handling, blowfish, python-cryptography

I want to encrypt a whole data of a pdf file using blowfish algorithm. I feel password protection is not enough. The pdf can contain images text tables etc. The pdf will be a thesis of PHD student.

Comment: Hi Anmol Singla, Could tell us what you tried, what issues you encountered and maybe detailing what you want? Do you want it still to be a PDF file that could be open by anybody or do you just want to encrypt the file (like any other file) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried that your file may be accessed by a malicious third-party then you should not attempt to implement your own algorithm. It is very easy to make a mistake that leads to security issues.

Also, you probably shouldn't be using the blowfish algorithm, which has some major security issues:

> Blowfish's use of a 64-bit block size (as opposed to e.g. AES's
> 128-bit block size) makes it vulnerable to birthday attacks,
> particularly in contexts like HTTPS. In 2016, the SWEET32 attack
> demonstrated how to leverage birthday attacks to perform plaintext
> recovery (i.e. decrypting ciphertext) against ciphers with a 64-bit
> block size.[9] The GnuPG project recommends that Blowfish not be used
> to encrypt files larger than 4 GB[10] due to its small block size.
>
> A reduced-round variant of Blowfish is known to be susceptible to
> known-plaintext attacks on reflectively weak keys. Blowfish
> implementations use 16 rounds of encryption, and are not susceptible
> to this attack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)#Weakness_and_successors

I would recommend using a well-established cryptography program that you can trust - something written by industry experts. It is unethical to store somebody else's private data using home-made encryption software that may or may not be secure.

Comment: actually we are making a website for our college phd students where they can upload there thesis for checking. as phd thesis are very confidential i want to encrypt them so that they cant be accessed by any 3rd party person. so what shall i do to protect thoses thesis